# Drywall glue didn't hold

Tags: drywall, adhesive

Installing drywall and after gluing and waiting for the glue to cure I realized that a lot of the glue did not adhere to the drywall and now the panels are loose and rattle. I think the glue skinned over before I got the panels on.

I used glue...because that's what I've seen other people do. I also used screws but just a lot less than if I only used screws. However, I now need to go back and use more screws because most of the glue didn't hold.

I thought I got the panels up fast enough, but I also was putting the sheets up in 20 degrees. I did use glue rated for cold weather application, I just don't know why it didn't adhere.

As a fix, do I just use more screws? I suppose I could take the panels down and reglue but that's a lot of work.

Comment: I have seen glue used in many locations usually it  is noticeable because the sheets are coming loose screws or nails are better with studs in my opinion.

Comment: Had to google drywall glue, it does seem to be a thing.  Next time when working in 20 degree weather, make sure it is a place that uses Celsius.

Comment: After a brief review of the top returns for "drywall glue" (most of which were _incredibly_ poorly written, always a red flag for me). I found a manufacturer site with instructions: Glue, then nail or screw. They list 2 advantages 1) they recommend about 1/2 the number of mechanical fasteners (every 12" instead of 6-8"). 2) They claim it reduces noise transmission, but don't say how much. With the added cost & time of applying the adhesive (and still having to screw it down), I'm not sure it comes out ahead.

Comment: Please revise your post to add context. What are you gluing _to_? Do you have access from the back side? Why did you use glue in the first place? Don't make us guess what you're doing.

Comment: Gluing drywall to standard studs 16 OC. I used glue because it's a standard practice where I am to use glue then half the amount of screws. I don't have backside access the the walls, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I'm by no means an expert, as this is the first I've ever heard of gluing up drywall. However, I'm going to suggest what seems to me to be some practical advice:

- If there's a bulge somewhere, I don't think there's any hope of fixing this beyond removing & replacing the sheet (or portion of it).

  - i.e. If it's glued securely at the top and bottom, but the middle will not flatten against the stud, you're toast. There's no way of pushing that "bubble" out.
  - You'll have to cut out the bubbled section and replace it with a smaller piece that will lay flat.
- If it's simply not securely fastened to the wall, drive another screw through the loose spots.

  - If this doesn't work, it's no more broken after the attempted fix than it was before, you just know that this is another spot that will have to be ripped out and replaced.
  - There's no rule against having "extra" screws holding the drywall up, it's a *minimum* fastener schedule, not a *maximum*.

If replacements become necessary, I don't think there's any need to pull out whole sheets, just cut out areas that you can't fix to your satisfaction and replace with patch pieces. Be sure to scrape any adhesive off the studs to get back to a smooth, flat surface or it will telegraph through as bumps in the finished drywall.

Do bear in mind that each new joint you add is one more untapered joint that you will have to tape and mud smooth or it will show through to your final painted surface - this alone could make it worthwhile replacing entire 4x8' sheets - it'll cost more up front, and be more frustrating, but the time & effort saved in finishing may more than make up for it.

Comment: Thanks, yes this is exactly what I ended up doing. I found the loose areas, thankfully they sat flush against the studs and just added a screw or more depending upon the size of the area. It ended up with a weird screw pattern but it worked. Now just hope the panels stay tight to the wall over the years. The walls all sound solid now, no more rattles of board bounce sound when banged on.